# Angular 2+ Catch event when shared object between components changes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template

I have 3 components (Sales, ProductSales, ProductTotals) that share an array of products but the ProductsTotal component is not reading the changes of the array. The father component (Sales) initializes the array of products and set as intnput for the child components, the ProductSales component changes the value of the array of products (add, remove, change properties like unit price, etc) and the ProductTotals component read the array and constantly does the operations to obtain the total of the sum of the unit prices of the products and displays them.

**SalesComponent.html**

```
<app-products-sale-total class="full-wid" [products]="products"></app-products-sale-total>
<app-products-sale class="full-wid" [products]="products"></app-products-sale>
```

To display the totals i did this
**ProductTotals.html**

```
{{products.length}}
<strong>Taxes:</strong> {{taxes|currency}} 
<strong>Subtotal:</strong> {{subtotal|currency}} 
<strong>Total:</strong> {{total|currency}}
```

**ProductsTotal.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, OnDestroy, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductSale } from '../product-sale-detail/product-sale-detail.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products-sale-total',
  templateUrl: './products-sale-total.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products-sale-total.component.scss']
})
export class ProductsSaleTotalComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() products: Array<ProductSale> = [];
  total: number = 0;
  subtotal: number = 0;
  taxes: number = 0;
  constructor() {
   }

  ngOnChanges(changes: import("@angular/core").SimpleChanges): void {
    calculateTotalFields();
    console.log(changes);
  }

  calculateTotalFields(): void {
    let total = 0;
    let subtotal = 0;
    let taxes = 0;
    this.products.forEach(x => {
      const totalProduct = x.UnitPrice * x.Quantity;
      const taxesProduct = totalProduct * 0.16;
      total += totalProduct;
      subtotal += totalProduct - taxesProduct;
      taxes += taxesProduct;
    });
    this.total = total;
    this.taxes = taxes;
    this.subtotal = subtotal;
  }
}
```

The problem is that only enters the ngOnChanges method once even though the object of products is changing.

The result of updating products in ProductsSalesComponent:

[image: result of updating products in ProductsSalesComponent]

**Edit**
I've created a project in StackBlitz to show the problem about how the ngOnChange event of the component 'ProductSaleTotal' is not fire when the object 'products' changes
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fcevey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproducts-sale-total%2Fproducts-sale-total.component.ts

Comment: You have to change reference of `product` array and then `onChanges()` fire. So simply you can use `destructuring`  `this.product = [ ... this.product, newObj ]`

Comment: @GaurangDhorda i've applied desstructuring in the method ngOnInit of ProductsSaleTotalsComponent and is still not firing the method ngOnChanges, the thing that has changed is that le message Products Length is not updating when the products changes in ProductsSaleComponent

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `behaviorsubject<T>` in service... And inject service to components for getting and sending data of products.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda i haven't tried the service with behaviorSubject but i've created the project in StackBlitz, maybe i made some mistake explaining the problem or something else

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cy6zup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproducts-sale-total%2Fproducts-sale-total.component.ts checkout this link I have changes lots of things in your code. First You need `@output()` for every `EventEmitter` then you can access one component output value to parent component.

Comment: Ohh thank you so much @GaurangDhorda i've check your code and works

Comment: welcome, I have answered the same... You can accept it too... Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app-products-sale-total` and `app-products-sale` are both different component, so to communicate with them you need to use `@Output()` from `app-products-sale` and pass array of object to `app-products-sale-total`... Complete working example you can find out here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cy6zup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsales-point%2Fsales-point.component.html)

Your **`ProductSaleDetailComponent.ts`** is...

```
export class ProductSaleDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() product: ProductSale;
    @Input () index: number;
    @Output() productData = new EventEmitter();
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.product.Quantity = 1;
    }

    changeInput(p){
        this.productData.emit({event: 'add',value:p, index : this.index});
    }
}
```

Your **ProductsSaleComponent** **template** is...

```
    <button type="button" (click)="addProduct()">Add Product!</button>
        <div *ngFor="let product of products; let i=index">
             <div> 
                 <app-product-sale-detail [product]="product" [index]="i" (productData)= "productOutput($event)" ></app-product-sale-detail>
             </div>
        <div>
            <button aria-label="Delete" color="warn" (click)="removeProduct(i)">
              Remove Product
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Your **ProductSaleComponent.ts** is...

```
export class ProductsSaleComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input() products: Array<ProductSale> = [];
   @Output() ProductOutputData = new EventEmitter(); 
   constructor() { }

   ngOnInit() {
      console.log('product Sale',new ProductSale());
   }

   addProduct() {
      this.products.push(new ProductSale());
   }

   removeProduct(index: number) {
      this.ProductOutputData.emit({event:'remove', index: index, value : this.products[index]} );
      this.products.splice(index, 1);
   }
   productOutput(event){
      this.ProductOutputData.emit(event);
   }
}
```

So, basically you need chain of `@Input() and`@Output()` to communicate between child-parent respectively..